# individual load with jquery ajax setInterval

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, load, while-loop

Im working on a script, that looks every second into the database for some configuration to display specific informations on a site.

my idea was, to set up a page with a setInterval function, to get informations from a php-file like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var check1 = '';
  var check2 = '';
  var refreshId = setInterval(function(){

    $.post('check.php', function(data) {
      var check1 = data;
    });

    while(check1 != check2){
      if(check1 == 'score'){
        $('#ajax').load('score.php');
      }
      if(check1 == 'stats'){
        $('#ajax').load('stats.php');
      }
      var check1 = check2;
    } 


  }, 1000);

});
```

My problem is, to reload the div #ajax only, when the var test will be changed to an other value. If the value is still the same, there should be no reaload of the div.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `var`s.

```
var check1 = data;
***
```

These will be making whole new check1 variables instead of referencing the one at the top of the code. Remove this `var` and also the one at the bottom:

```
var check1 = check2;
***
```

Comment: i dont understand why, because i need something to check if the content of 'check.php' has changed.

Also i guess, the setInterval function will stop my while loop?!

Comment: Because you have three different variables, all called 'check1'. You actually only want one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(check1 != check2){
  if(check1 == 'score'){
    $('#ajax').load('score.php');
  }
  if(check1 == 'stats'){
    $('#ajax').load('stats.php');
  }
  check2 = check1 ;
}
```

Replace the while with 'if' and var check2=check1; from var check1=check2;